# How to set JVM to have more 1GB stack size?

Tags: java, jvm, stack, stack-overflow

My OS info is as below:

```
Linux 3.1.10-1.16-default #1 SMP Wed Jun 27 05:21:40 UTC 2012 (d016078) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My JDK info is:

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.3) (suse-6.2-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

But if I use more than 1GB stack,

```
 java -Xss2g -Xmx100g Test
```

I got this:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:657)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.<clinit>(Reference.java:162)
```

So, how could I use more than 1GB stack?

Use "ulimit -a" I got this:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1291902
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1291902
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

From this, it seems the stack size limit is just 8MB. But it succeeded with 1GB.

Comment: 1 GB of stack seems very excessive, especially for Java. Are you certain you need that much? Your OS may have a limit on the amount of stack size per thread (see `ulimit -a`).

Comment: If you need that much stack, perhaps you want to rethink your design.

Comment: How much RAM do you have in your machine? how much is it free?

Comment: does "ulimit -a" show any memory related limitation?

Comment: stack size is tipically measured in kilobytes...why do you need gigabytes?

Comment: Stack is a memory place where the methods and the local variables are stored... why do you need such a huge one?

Comment: You might want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337711/outof-memory-error-while-working-on-large-dataset

Comment: Java doesn't place objects on the stack like some other languages so it shouldn't need to be so large. Setting the memory so high suggest you need to profile your application to understand how memory is being used and find ways to minimise it.

Comment: @Luxspes Methods are not stored on the stack.

Comment: You could check out http://candrews.integralblue.com/2009/01/preventing-outofmemoryerror-native-thread/ & http://nicodewet.com/2012/02/05/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new-native-thread/

Comment: Or http://devgrok.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/resolving-outofmemoryerror-unable-to.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need either a 2G stack or a 100G heap, and in any event your physical hardware is most unlikely to be able to supply them. Why are you using such enormous numbers?